# In App purchases or payment system iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway

I am making an iOS app that involves the idea of storing money in an account very similar to paypal.We will allow a user to use a CC to add credit to the account and then credit will be spent on a service outside the app. Key thing to note is it is a service not a product.

My question here is according to Apple guidelines do you think we would need to just use in-app purchases because we are selling a service that is a non tangle object or can we use a payment system in order to keep money in the account?

Any help on the matter will be much appreciated maybe if someone has done something similiar and can spread light on the manner.

Comment: What does the App do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use IAP for things that aren't consumed in the app. Don't let them buy shout outs via IAP if they can't use shout outs in the app.

Also, if you are going to unlock features for those who've paid, you must allow them to pay via IAP.

Comment: To clarify the purchase of a product can still be used though just not through IAP? Correct? Can you be more clear by what you mean when you talk about additional features? The consumer has credit and then he or she will just keep using the credit for shout outs nothing more.

Comment: @Krzemienski, Correct, physical goods can be sold through an app, but not with IAP. Regarding features, I'm saying that if you can only send shout outs if you've paid, then you must allow people to purchase shoutouts via IAP. You can't withhold features without letting people buy them via IAP. The only way around this is to have a free version (without shoutouts), and a paid version with unlimited shout outs.

Comment: So in theory they can do both.